# jQuery not retruning data-id after the first use of the button

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I have a php script that creates a table and each id in the table has an edit button. The edit button looks like this.

```
<button data-siteid="'.$row->site_sn_id.'" class="btn btn-link p-0 m-0" style="font-size:.7rem" id="editBtn" type="button" >Edit</button>
```

The number of buttons varies but I am trying to get the data-siteid passed to an ajax call like this.

```
$("#editBtn").on("click", function(){
        var siteID = $(this).data('siteid');
        $.ajax({
            method: "POST",
            url: "edit-modal.php",
            data: {siteID: siteID}
        })
                .done(function( msg ) {
                    $('#editModal').modal('show');
                    $("#bodyContent").html(msg);
                });
    });
```

Its working on the first edit button of the table but it does nothing after that first button. It wont even open the modal.

Comment: id must be unique throughout the page

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason is because ID should be unique across your HTML page and it looks like you're defining multiple elements with the same ID.

So, instead, try adding and using a class selector:

```
<button class="... editBtn" ...

$(".editBtn").on("click", function() {
...
```

Comment: So simple. This has been driving me nuts. Thank you.

Comment: Accept the answer if it answered your question, so that others can save time.